# Can't POST order to Prestashop API due to null order object

Tags: php, xml, prestashop-1.7

recently I had this error where everytime I send orders to the prestashop API it just returns 500 Internal Server Error.

Found out that it was the module XML tag, and I corrected it. But that's solved and another error related to the payment is popping on the logs:

> Call to a member function addOrderPayment() on null in
> /var/www/vhosts/vitrosepstore.com/subdomains/proves/httpdocs/classes/PaymentModule.php
> on line 428

Inside the `validateOrder()` function in `PaymentModule.php` class, the `addOrderPayment` call line breaks. I'm not familar with php, but looks like the `$order` object seems to be null.

```php
>>>>> if (!$order->addOrderPayment($amount_paid, null, $transaction_id)) {
            PrestaShopLogger::addLog('PaymentModule::validateOrder - Cannot save Order Payment', 3, null, 'Cart', (int) $id_cart, true);
            throw new PrestaShopException('Can\'t save Order Payment');
      }
```

This is the xml that I'm trying to post to the API:

```xml
<prestashop>
  <order>
    <id_address_delivery>78</id_address_delivery>
    <id_address_invoice>78</id_address_invoice>
    <id_cart>356</id_cart>
    <id_lang>1</id_lang>
    <id_currency>1</id_currency>
    <id_customer>76</id_customer>
    <id_carrier>1</id_carrier>
    <current_state>15</current_state>
    <module>ps_cashondelivery</module>
    <invoice_number>0</invoice_number>
    <invoice_date>0000-00-00 00:00:00</invoice_date>
    <delivery_number>0</delivery_number>
    <delivery_date>0000-00-00 00:00:00</delivery_date>
    <valid>0</valid>
    <date_add>2020-10-07 09:06:22</date_add>
    <date_upd>2020-10-07 09:06:22</date_upd>
    <shipping_number />
    <id_shop_group>1</id_shop_group>
    <id_shop>1</id_shop>
    <secure_key />
    <payment>Free order</payment>
    <recyclable>0</recyclable>
    <gift>0</gift>
    <gift_message />
    <mobile_theme>0</mobile_theme>
    <total_discounts>0</total_discounts>
    <total_discounts_tax_incl>0</total_discounts_tax_incl>
    <total_discounts_tax_excl>0</total_discounts_tax_excl>
    <total_paid>0</total_paid>
    <total_paid_tax_incl>0</total_paid_tax_incl>
    <total_paid_tax_excl>0</total_paid_tax_excl>
    <total_paid_real>0</total_paid_real>
    <total_products>0</total_products>
    <total_products_wt>0</total_products_wt>
    <total_shipping>0</total_shipping>
    <total_shipping_tax_incl>0</total_shipping_tax_incl>
    <total_shipping_tax_excl>0</total_shipping_tax_excl>
    <carrier_tax_rate>0</carrier_tax_rate>
    <total_wrapping>0</total_wrapping>
    <total_wrapping_tax_incl>0</total_wrapping_tax_incl>
    <total_wrapping_tax_excl>0</total_wrapping_tax_excl>
    <round_mode>0</round_mode>
    <round_type>0</round_type>
    <conversion_rate>1</conversion_rate>
    <reference />
    <associations>
      <order_rows>
       .
       .
       .
       .
      </order_rows>
    </associations>
  </order>
</prestashop>
```

Just in case somebody needs to take a look on the php class, I'll link it down below. Line 241:

[PaymentModule.php](https://pastebin.com/eFD2UGEq)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your XML payload in a single line (without return carriages),
I had a similar issue in the past and this did the trick.